# Is there a way to change the color of my code based on my criteria?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I know you can change to dark/light, etc.

But what if I want to do this:

1. Properties are purple.
2. Classes are blue.
3. etc.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bit of a hassle, but this is an option: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YourColorfulVisualStudio2012WithTheColorThemeEditorVS2010ColorsToo.aspx

Comment: thanks! ill give this a try. i need to wait 4 mins before accepting ur answer.